# Make script run when awaited promise is resolved

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, async-await

I want to have a script fetch the link to an image of a cat using the Pexels API and then make that image link set as the src of an image.

I tried to add some loading text to make it less boring while you are waiting for the image link, but when I tried adding it after the await code. I know await doesn't work by pausing the code but instead making the await code happen when the promise is resolved. The issue is I don't know how to make the text disappear after the image appears.

```
let page = Math.ceil(Math.random()*1000);

var imageLink = fetch('https://api.pexels.com/v1/search?query=cat&per_page=1&page=' + page,{
  headers: {
    Authorization: apiKey
  }
}).then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
  return response.json();
}).then((data) => {
  return data.photos[0].src.original;
})

async function main() {
  document.getElementById('image').src = await imageLink;
  document.getElementById('loadingText').innerHTML = '';
  console.log(imageLink);
}

main();
```

Comment: You're hiding the `loadingText` as soon as you fetched the photo url from the api and made the `image` load it, but you're not waiting until the image itself has loaded the photo. You'll need an `onload` handler on the image element for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can wait for the image element to finish loading via:

```js
const waitForImageToLoad = async (imgElem) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (imgElem.complete) return res();
    imgElem.onload = () => resolve();
    imgElem.onerror = () => reject(imgElem);
});
```

Usage:

```js
const main = async () => {
  showLoadingMask();
  imageEl.src = await fetchRandomCatImage();
  await waitForImageToLoad(imageEl); // wait to finish
  hideLoadingMask();
};
```

Full demo:

**Note:** Replace `<API_KEY>` with your API key.

```js
const
  API_URL = 'https://api.pexels.com',
  API_KEY = '<API_KEY>',
  MAX_PAGE = 10;

const defaultHeaders = { Authorization: API_KEY };

const
  loadingMask = document.querySelector('#loading-mask'),
  imageEl = document.querySelector('#image');

const main = async () => {
  showLoadingMask();
  imageEl.src = await fetchRandomCatImage();
  await waitForImageToLoad(imageEl); // wait to finish
  hideLoadingMask();
};

const fetchRandomCatImage = async () => {
  const url = randomImageUrl('cat');
  const response = await fetch(url, { headers: defaultHeaders });
  const data = await response.json();
  return data.photos[0].src.original;
};

const waitForImageToLoad = async (imgEl) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (imgEl.complete) return resolve();
    imgEl.onload = () => resolve();
    imgEl.onerror = () => reject(imgEl);
});

const randomImageUrl = (query) => {
  const url = new URL(API_URL);
  url.pathname = 'v1/search';
  url.searchParams.append('query', query);
  url.searchParams.append('page', randomInt(MAX_PAGE));
  return url.toString();
}

const showLoadingMask = () => {
  loadingMask.classList.add('is-loading');
}

const hideLoadingMask = () => {
  loadingMask.classList.remove('is-loading');
}

const randomInt = (limit) => Math.ceil(Math.random() * limit);

main();
```

```css
*. *::before. *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from { opacity: 1; }
  to { opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  to { opacity: 1; }
}

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #222;
}

#loading-mask {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #FFF;
  animation: opacity 3s fadeOut;
}

#loading-mask.is-loading {
  display: flex;
  opacity: 1;
  animation: opacity 3s fadeIn;
}

#image {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="loading-mask">Loading...</div>
<img id="image" />
```

Comment: @Bergi I corrected this.